# Aggregations and filtering with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Using ES 1.5.2

Speaking strictly of aggregations, is it better for performance?
The query/filter/aggregation returns the exact same result in both cases.

- Filter query and then aggregate.

  ```
  {
      "size":0,
      "query": {},
      "aggs": {}
  }
  ```
- Or filter inside the aggregate.

  ```
  {
      "size":0,
      "aggs": {
          "filter": {
              "query": {},
          },
          "aggs": {}
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: "better" in what sense? Are you looking for "better" performance, "better" accuracy, "better" results? Please explain your use case.

Comment: Added the extra info. Is it better for performance? Both queries return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between filtering and quering ist that filters do not affect scoring.

Filters only reduce the result set size, but there is no relevance scoring on the matched items at all.

Comment: Yeah, don't care about scoring, just for pure aggregations. I.e: 
"Give me the average sales amount for the day".

Comment: Actually, I just did a test with Jmeter 10 users/threads. On average, filter first to reduce the result set and then aggregate, is at least twice as fast. 600ms resp vs 1400ms resp. I guess resource are used differently to0.

Comment: Filters are also cached, whereas queries are not by default.